# Log file writing extremely delayed in WebSphere App Server

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am experiencing an issue with delayed writes to the application logs for a Java EE web application running in IBM WebSphere v. 7.x. Logging statements taking up to an hour to appear in the application logs.

The problem doesn't appear related to heavy loads; WAS is responding to page requests almost instantly, and I am testing against a box that isn't used for performance testing, and on a holiday no less -- there is very little activitiy on the server.

My guess would be that the thread associated with logging has been configured with very low priority, but I cant figure out where that would be configured via the admin console or the configuration files.

Has anyone else experienced this sort of issue with WebSphere?

Comment: aren't you buffering before writing output ? which logging mechanism are you using ? are there any other applications in your environment experiencing similar problems or yours is the only on?

Comment: The application is using slf4j as the facade over java's core logging facilities (i.e. java.util.logging). The problematic app is the only one I have deployed in the environment, so I have other data points to compare to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's possible you don't even enough available threads in the thread pool. Its consistant with the page requests being fast, as they are controlled by the WebContainer threads.

Try increasing it:

Servers > Application Servers > Thread pools > ...
Not sure exactly which one to increase its max value. In worst case, increase'em all. Increase it heavily, so to be sure.

Other options:
make sure you enough disk space / try to connect with jConsole to inquire.

Comment: Having the same issue.  Did you ever figure out which setting to tweak?   I'm nervous to just tweak my client's server without a solid reasoning as to why. @ScottW